# Can not clear cache memory on Linux

Tags: linux, caching, memory

I have Logstash and Elasticsearch running on an EC2 (8GB ram), ArchLinux.

I can not clear the cached memory (I understand kernel should be able to claim this memory back if needed). from the `meminfo`, I understand that the most of the cached memory is inactive, which means no process is using that,so I should be able to clear it, right?.

I am doing `sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` to clear the memory.
Only system reboot is clearing this memory.
There could be a memory leak, how can I see which process is using this cache memory.

```
cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:        7661268 kB
MemFree:          613144 kB
MemAvailable:     561144 kB
Buffers:            8580 kB
Cached:          2271144 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           165424 kB
Inactive:        2244356 kB
Active(anon):     152528 kB
Inactive(anon):  2226088 kB
Active(file):      12896 kB
Inactive(file):    18268 kB
Unevictable:     4429248 kB
Mlocked:         4429248 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               164 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       4559304 kB
Mapped:            33916 kB
Shmem:           2226220 kB
Slab:              54908 kB
SReclaimable:      33764 kB
SUnreclaim:        21144 kB
KernelStack:        1176 kB
PageTables:        11832 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3830632 kB
Committed_AS:    6861504 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       19132 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359707084 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   4329472 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       10240 kB
DirectMap2M:     7985152 kB
```

Output of a `top`:

```
top - 06:04:57 up 16 days, 17:12,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.04, 1.39
Tasks:  76 total,   1 running,  75 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.2 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   7661268 total,  7051140 used,   610128 free,     9772 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  2272468 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                     
19958 elastic+  20   0 9746648 4.273g  22760 S   0.3 58.5   1:11.36 java                                                                        
19970 root      20   0 1008496  89912   3876 S   0.3  1.2   0:07.13 node                                                                        
19932 root      20   0   28256   6728   6496 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.29 systemd-journal                                                             
    1 root      20   0  110052   3316   1596 S   0.0  0.0   1:45.84 systemd                                                                     
19856 root      20   0   16136   2100   1460 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.05 bash                                                                        
19851 root      20   0   82472   2040   1136 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.39 sshd                                                                        
  245 haproxy   20   0   28872   1996    624 S   0.0  0.0   4:01.48 haproxy                                                                     
19854 root      20   0  157700   1980      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 (sd-pam)                                                                    
  244 haproxy   20   0   28596   1728    768 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 haproxy                                                                     
  221 systemd+  20   0   23496   1476   1056 S   0.0  0.0   0:04.99 systemd-network                                                             
20197 root      20   0   17544   1464   1064 R   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 top                                                                         
  149 root      20   0   31016   1456    768 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.10 systemd-udevd                                                               
  233 root      20   0   39980   1448    860 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.03 sshd                                                                        
  217 root      20   0   13204   1344    796 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.55 crond                                                                       
  219 dbus      20   0   24748   1236    900 S   0.0  0.0   0:18.18 dbus-daemon                                                                 
  229 systemd+  20   0   18164   1196    980 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.92 systemd-resolve                                                             
19853 root      20   0   26764   1168    700 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 systemd                                                                     
  218 root      20   0   15252   1144    876 S   0.0  0.0   0:07.26 systemd-logind                                                              
  194 root      16  -4  105484   1136    764 S   0.0  0.0   0:03.15 auditd                                                                      
  214 root      20   0   19240   1024    776 S   0.0  0.0   1:08.62 irqbalance                                                                  
  226 root      20   0    8124    820    700 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 agetty                                                                      
  225 root      20   0    8124    816    700 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 agetty                                                                      
  224 root      20   0    8124    792    680 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 agetty                                                                      
  242 root      20   0   23896    624    292 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 haproxy-systemd                                                             
  213 root      20   0    9324    612    420 S   0.0  0.0   9:44.04 rngd                                                                        
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.16 kthreadd                                                                    
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.7  0.0  65:18.76 ksoftirqd/0                                                                 
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                                                
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  10:08.87 rcu_sched                                                                   
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh                                                                      
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.36 migration/0                                                                 
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.17 watchdog/0                                                                  
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.91 watchdog/1                                                                  
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.37 migration/1
```

Answer (score 0):

First - the `echo` command you gave should be clearing the page cache.  This is the same command given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system).

The page cache is managed by the kernel.  It is not used (at least directly) by any process.  The memory used by the page cache is available to be given to any process if the kernel decides to do that.  The memory has not been leaked.

If you want to do an experiment, write a program which repeatedly writes to every page in a 4 or 6 gigabyte space.  You will see the size of the page cache drop.

Comment: I have read some where that echo command doesn't always release the memory, when some program is actively accessing some files.

even if I stop the program(logstash) that is supposedly causing this memory behaviour, It doesn't clear the memory. 

are you saying that there isn't any memory leak? can you please tell me on what basis you have arrived at this conclusion? 

I have observed that deleting the text files which logstash has processed, clears up this memory.

Comment: The kernel uses the page cache to speed file I/O.  It doesn't know when a program stops using a particular file.  Instead, the pages allocated to a file that is no longer being used will eventually be reused for some other purpose.   I have seen this happen often - if a program demands most of available memory, the size of the page cache drops to nearly 0.

Comment: I had OOM killer killing my applications in this case, which means kernel couldn't take back the memory, which could probably be because some application (logstash) is using those files? does kernel can clear page cache if some application is using it actively?

Comment: @vangap - I think you should post another question on this.   I've never come across an OOM killer.